# If I want to compile a dynamic library through gcc, do I need to use - static? What is the difference between with '-static' and without '-static'

Tags: c, gcc, compiler-errors, shared-libraries, bazel

What is the difference between with `-static` and without `-static`

when I use gcc to compile a shared library with `-static`

I got an error

```
/usr/sbin/ld.gold: error: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/13.2.1/crtbeginT.o: requires dynamic R_X86_64_32 reloc against '__TMC_END__' which may overflow at runtime; recompile with -fPIC
```

When I  searched for the solution of this error with Google, I found that this seems like a classic problem.

if I want to make it work, I should do that.

```
cp crtbeginS.o crtbeginT.o
```

so, If I compile a dynamic library using gcc, what is the difference between with `-static` and without `-static`.

And, should I compile a shared library with `-static`?

by the way, when I using cc_shared_libray to build a shared library in bazel, this mistake also occurs, It seems like the cc_shared_library compile shared library with `-static` by default

Comment: No, you should not use `-static`.

Comment: More precisely, when linking a shared library you should use the `-shared` _instead_ of `-static`.

Answer (score 0):

just use the -shared instead of -static